# Sort list in a numeric order

Tags: python

I plan to sort the following list in a numeric order

```
In [117]: print(alist)
['1. Introduction', '10. Functional Programming Modules', '11. File and Directory Access',
'12. Data Persistence', '13. Data Compression and Archiving', '14. File Formats', '15. Cryptographic Services', '16. Generic Operating System Services', '17. Concurrent Execution', 
'18. Interprocess Communication and Networking', '19. Internet Data Handling', '2. Built-in Function', '20. Structured Markup Processing Tools', '21. Internet Protocols and Support', '22. Multimedia Services', '23. Internationalization', '24. Program Frameworks', '25. Graphical User Interfaces with Tk', '26. Development Tools', '27. Debugging and Profiling', '28. Software Packaging and Distribution', '29. Python Runtime Services', '3. Built-in Constants', '30. Custom Python Interpreters', '31. Importing Modules', '32. Python Language Services', '33. Miscellaneous Services', '34. MS Windows Specific Services', '35. Unix Specific Services', '36. Superseded Modules', '37. Undocumented Modules', '4. Built-in Types', '5. Built-in Exceptions', '6. Text Processing Services', '7. Binary Data Services', '8. Data Types', '9. Numeric and Mathematical Modules']
```

I tried `sorted`, `sort()`, but get the same result.

The result I desire is

```
['1.**', '2.**',... '10.**',... '19.**', '20.**'...]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass a `key` to apply your *custom-sort* wishes.

```
res = sorted(alist, key=lambda x: int(x.partition('.')[0]))
```

What this `lambda` does is that it takes the strings one-by-one, *extracts* the value in front of the dot (`'.'`) and converts it to `int`. Based on that integer value the `list` is sorted and returned.

---

**Notes:**

There are some assumptions built-in to the `lambda`. If whatever comes before the first dot cannot be cast to `int` an Error will be thrown. To circumvent that you can use the following, more elaborate, version:

```
def sort_helper(my_str, str_last=True):
  try:
    return int(my_str.partition('.')[0])  # kudos @JonClements
  except ValueError:
    return float('{}inf'.format({True: '+', False: '-'}[str_last])) # sends malformed inputs to the front or the back depending on the str_last flag

alist = ['1. Introduction', '5. Built-in Exceptions', 'X. Not Implemented Yet']
res = sorted(alist, key=sort_helper)
print(res)  # ['1. Introduction', '5. Built-in Exceptions', 'X. Not Implemented Yet']
```

or:

```
res = sorted(alist, key=lambda x: sort_helper(x, False))
print(res)  # ['X. Not Implemented Yet', '1. Introduction', '5. Built-in Exceptions']
```

Comment: You should probably either limit the split to 1 occurrence or use `str.partition` - no need to split the entire string on *every* `.`

Comment: @JonClements I do not see any strings with multiple ones but, sure.

Comment: `str.partition` only ever generates a 3-tuple and is very fast at doing so - more so that using `str.split` with a maxsplit of 1... so I'd still recommend that... Also - to put things first or last - you can default to using `float('-inf')` or `float('inf')` - can't imagine it'd be needed here but it's a fairly robust general approach and useful to know.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the comments and info!

Comment: I'd personally have gone for `return float('inf') if str_last else float('-inf')` but okay... :) That way you've got constants and not generating one from string formatting and a dictlookup but, I'm just getting nitpicky there

Comment: @JonClements I just wanted to add a *touch of fancy*. I initially wrote it as you say. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = ['1. Introduction', '4. End', '2. Chapter 1', '3. Chapter 2']
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda s: int(s[:s.index('.')]))
['1. Introduction', '2. Chapter 1', '3. Chapter 2', '4. End']
```

Comment: @PM2Ring At this point I just see it as an alternative to Ev. Kounis' better answer who already explained what the `key` does very well.